# Jupyter Notebook command failing in Qiskit

Tags: python, anaconda, qiskit

I have Qiskit installed via Anaconda and a virtual environment set up in Python 3.8. When I run the command `jupyter notebook` in the Anaconda prompt I get an error. I'm not sure what the problem is. How do I fix it?

```
(.venv) C:\Users\brenm>pip install qiskit
```

Requirement already satisfied: qiskit in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (0.23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-ignis==0.5.1 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.11.1 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-terra==0.16.1 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-aqua==0.8.1 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-aer==0.7.1 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11>=2.4 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-terra==0.16.1 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cython>=0.27.1 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (0.29.21)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=5 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (5.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-terra==0.16.1 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-ignis==0.5.1 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: fastdtw in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (0.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.20.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (0.23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: dlx in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: yfinance in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (0.1.55)
Requirement already satisfied: docplex in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (2.19.202)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy>=1.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: retworkx>=0.5.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (0.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.1.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (51.0.0.post20201207)
Requirement already satisfied: quandl in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (3.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from docplex->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (2.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from docplex->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from pandas->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from pandas->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (2020.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from docplex->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from docplex->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (2.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.21.1 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.11.1->qiskit) (1.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from pandas->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-terra==0.16.1 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-ntlm>=1.1.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.11.1->qiskit) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nest-asyncio!=1.1.0,>=1.0.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.11.1->qiskit) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets>=8 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.11.1->qiskit) (8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-terra==0.16.1 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.20.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (0.23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.1.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (51.0.0.post20201207)
Requirement already satisfied: dill>=0.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.16.1->qiskit) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=5 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (5.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: fastjsonschema>=2.10 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.16.1->qiskit) (2.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-constraint>=1.4 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.16.1->qiskit) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from pandas->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx>=2.2 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.16.1->qiskit) (2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: ply>=3.10 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.16.1->qiskit) (3.11)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy>=1.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: retworkx>=0.5.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (0.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=2.6 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.16.1->qiskit) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from docplex->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->qiskit-terra==0.16.1->qiskit) (0.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.1.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (51.0.0.post20201207)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->qiskit-terra==0.16.1->qiskit) (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.3.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from networkx>=2.2->qiskit-terra==0.16.1->qiskit) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: inflection>=0.3.1 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from quandl->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from pandas->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from quandl->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (8.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from docplex->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (2.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from docplex->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from requests->docplex->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from requests->docplex->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.21.1 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.11.1->qiskit) (1.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from requests->docplex->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: ntlm-auth>=1.0.2 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from requests-ntlm>=1.1.0->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.11.1->qiskit) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from docplex->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (2.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=1.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from requests-ntlm>=1.1.0->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.11.1->qiskit) (3.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from docplex->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=1.3->requests-ntlm>=1.1.0->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.11.1->qiskit) (1.14.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=1.3->requests-ntlm>=1.1.0->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.11.1->qiskit) (2.20)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.20.0->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.20.0->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from sympy>=1.3->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=4.5.1 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from yfinance->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (4.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from docplex->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (2.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.3 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.7.1->qiskit) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: multitasking>=0.0.7 in c:\users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\lib\site-packages (from yfinance->qiskit-aqua==0.8.1->qiskit) (0.0.9)

(.venv) C:\Users\brenm>jupyter notebook
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$ python -m notebook
```

If this still fails, try

```
$ python -m pip install jupyter --user
$ jupyter notebook
```